# fluentd v0.14でfluent-plugin-datacounterが動かない

Tags: fluentd

いつもお世話になっております。

httpdのアクセスログを、fluentdで件数をカウントしたいと考えております。
fluent-plugin-datacounterで実現できると思ったのですが、
fluentdを起動した時に以下のエラーロクが表示され起動されませんでした。
解決手段が分からなくご教授頂けると幸いです。

エラー内容

```
2017-02-28 19:27:20 +0900 [warn]: both of Plugin @id and path for <storage> are not specified. Using on-memory store.
2017-02-28 19:27:20 +0900 [error]: dry run failed: undefined method `workers' for #<Fluent::SystemConfig:0x007fade2d53620>
```

環境

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.8 (Final)

# td-agent --version
td-agent 0.14.11

# ruby --version
ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-linux]

# td-agent-gem list --local | grep fluent-plugin-datacounter
fluent-plugin-datacounter (1.0.0)
```

httpdのアクセスログ形式(tlsv形式)

```
2017-02-28 19:25:13.000000000 +0900 httpd.access: {"forwardedfor":"-","host":"127.0.0.1","req":"OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0","status":"200","size":"0","referer":"-","ua":"Apache (internal dummy connection)","reqtime_microsec":"284","cache":"-","runtime":"-","vhost":"-"}
```

設定内容

```
# vi /etc/td-agent/td-agent.d/httpd_count.conf
<source>
  @type tail
  path /var/log/httpd/access_log
  pos_file /var/log/td-agent/pos/access_log.pos
  tag httpd.access
  format ltsv
  time_key     time
  time_format  %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z
</source>
<match httpd.**>
  @type datacounter
  count_interval 1m
  count_key status
  pattern1 2xx ^2\d\d$
</match>
<match **>
  @type stdout
</match>
```

お手数ですがよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 私の環境だと v0.14.13 で正常に動いてます。よく分かりませんがバグっぽいエラーに思えるのでバージョンアップを試してみるとどうでしょう。

Comment: ご指摘の通りバグぽかったです。td-agent-gem update fluentdしたらエラーなく正常に動作することができました！ありがとうございます！

Comment: 興味本位でお尋ねしますがtlsv形式ってどんな形式でしょうか。ltsvのtypoかなとも思ったのですが、見たところlabel部分がないので違うのかな、と。

Comment: すみません、誤字致しました。LTSV形式になります(http://ltsv.org/)。これを設定しております。LogFormat "time:%{%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z}t\tforwardedfor:%{X-Forwarded-For}i\thost:%h\treq:%r\tstatus:%>s\tsize:%B\treferer:%{Referer}i\tua:%{User-Agent}i\treqtime_microsec:%D\tcache:%{X-Cache}o\truntime:%{X-Runtime}o\tvhost:%{Host}i" ltsv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメントにあります通りアップデートしたら改善されました。
td-agent-gem update fluentd